# How to add text from two files in awk

Tags: join, awk

I have two tab delim files as shown below:

```
FileA.txt   
1     a,b,c
2     b,c,e
3     e,d,f,a

FileB.txt
a    xxx
b    xyx
c    zxxy
```

I would need the output in the below way:

```
Output:
1     a,b,c    xxx,xyx.zxxy
2     b,c,e    xyx,zxxy,e
3     e,d,f,a  e,d,f,xxx
```

The comma separated values in $2 of FileA are to be used as key to search for a match in $1 of FileB and add a new column in the output with their values in $2 from FileB. Incase of no match it should print the original value. Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
               {NF++; s=""; n=split($2,t,","); 
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {k=t[i]; 
                                   $NF=$NF s ((k in a)?a[k]:k);           
                                   s=","}}1' fileB fileA | column -t

1  a,b,c    xxx,xyx,zxxy
2  b,c,e    xyx,zxxy,e
3  e,d,f,a  e,d,f,xxx
```